# react native 0.55.4 navigation parameter not able to get on another screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
<TouchableOpacity 
                onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('BookOrder', {
              itemId: 86,
              otherParam: 'anything you want here',
            });
          }} >

</TouchableOpacity>
```

when i click on TouchableOpacity. I cant get the parameter on another screen

```
 const { navigation } = this.props;
        const itemId = navigation.getParam('itemId', 'NO-ID');
        const otherParam = navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'some default value');

<Text >Got Data: {JSON.stringify(itemId)}  </Text>
<Text >Got Data: {JSON.stringify(otherParam)}  </Text>
```

but i can't get the itemId it display's default value 'NO-ID' and 'some default value'.

I am using below version of react-native
react-native-cli: 1.2
react-native: 0.55.4

Comment: in BookOrder page itemId seen as 86 and otherParam  see as 'anything you want here'. Do you want to see some default value on BookOrder, i think you should set at component where you navigate it.

Comment: No actually i want to get "86" and "anything you want here" on my "BookOrder" Screnn, but i am only getting the default values like  'NO-ID' and 'some default value'.

Comment: whats your react-navigation version? I compile "^1.5.13" version and it works correctly? or you can try to write console console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.itemId) whats on the console?

Answer (score 0):

try to access your params like below:

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
const {itemId, otherParam } = navigation.state.params
```

Comment: <TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 5, marginBottom: 5}} 
                onPress={() => {           
            this.props.navigation.navigate('BookOrder', {
              itemId: 86,
              otherParam: 'anything you want here',
            });   -----  on other BookOrder Screen I am using this code ------- const { navigation } = this.props;
        const itemId = navigation.getParam('itemId', 'NO-ID');
        const otherParam = navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'some default value');

Comment: Please update your question with full code. It's not readable from comments. You should show navigation stacks and other related codes.